# cabal + proxy: downloading packages from hackage

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal

I'm using Haskell Platform 7.10.2-a (64-bit) on Windows:

```
>cabal -V
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.4.0 of the Cabal library
```

My proxy requires (basic HTTP) authentication:

```
>set http_proxy=http://user:passwd@acme.com:port
```

It seems to work for `cabal update`:

```
> cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Skipping download: Local and remote files match.
```

However, when I try to install any package, it fails:

```
> cabal get ghc-mod
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
cabal: There is no package named 'ghc-mod'.

>cabal install shelltestrunner
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
cabal: There is no package named 'shelltestrunner'.
You may need to run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available
packages.
```

How can I get `get` or `install` to actually use the proxy? Or is there some other problem preventing installation of packages from hackage?

Comment: this seems strange: *Skipping download: Local and remote files match.* - I doubt that even this step succeeds. It's probably your env.setting :(

Comment: btw: AFAIK cabal should use your system-settings (works on windows for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the cause, when using `cabal -v update`, it displays path like

`\\ACME.NET\UserData\username\RF\AppData\Roaming\cabal\packages\hackage.haskell.org\00-index.tar.gz`

while other uses of cabal use path like `C:\Users\username\AppData\..`, but *without* the `RF` folder in the displayed path. Must be my company network server config. Anyway, I updated paths like `remote-repo-cache` to use another folder in `cabal/config` and it works better now.